# excluding numbers from a filter

Tags: python-3.x, filter, output

I am filtering a bunch of numbers from a string. The code I have to do that is:

```
def fun(variable):
    numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', '$']
    if variable in numbers:
        return True
    else:
        return False


sequence = stats
filtered = filter(fun, sequence)
print('The filtered numbers are:')
for s in filtered:
    print(s)
```

Variable "stats" is a string of characters like "24hour low: $13.45"
When the code is run, it will provide an output of 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5
However, I want to exclude numbers like 24 that do not matter in terms of pure data.
What changes do I have to make to get this?
Also I am new to python and coding in general so forgive me for any ignorance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you expect / want?

Comment: @meshi rather than "24hour low: $13.45" my goal is to just get the 1345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach the problem differently.

Assuming that all your data strings follow a pattern of "<some words>: $<some digits>" then you can use the `.split` method on the strings. If you split the strings on the "$", the last item in the returned list is a string that can be cast into a float.

```
def get_price(string):
    """Return the last token from splitting a string on the '$' as a float."""
    return float(string.split("$")[-1])

data = ["24hour low: $13.45", "24hour high: $23.45"]

print(list(map(get_price, data)))

# A list comprehension that is the equivalent of the above.
print([get_price(item) for item in data])
```

OUTPUT: `[13.45, 23.45]`

Update: I just saw your comment. If you want a string of digits you could use this code.

```
def get_price(string):
    """Return the last token from splitting a string on the '$'
    followed by a split on the '.' 
    followed by a join with an empty string ''."""
    return "".join(string.split("$")[-1].split("."))

data = ["24hour low: $13.45", "24hour high: $23.45"]

print(list(map(get_price, data)))

# A list comprehension which is the equivalent of the above.
print([get_price(item) for item in data])
```

OUTPUT: `['1345', '2345']`

If you insist on using `filter`, here is an example that checks if each character is a digit. Then slice and join items index 2 to the end. That removes the '24'.

```
def is_digit(string):
    return string.isdigit()

stats = "24hour low: $13.45"
print(''.join(filter(is_digit, stats))[2:])
```

OUTPUT: '1345'

Update: I am assuming that you have a list of strings. Here is an example.

```
data = ["24hour low: $13.45", "24hour high: $23.45"]

print([''.join(filter(is_digit, string))[2:] for string in data])
```

OUTPUT: `['1345', '2345']`

Update after comment that includes a sample string:

```
SAMPLE_STRING = "Key metrics24 Hour Low$21.2024 Hour High$22.90Net change$0.616816"

nested_tokens = [
    [''.join(filter(is_digit, item)) for item in token.split()]
    for token in SAMPLE_STRING.replace(
        "Net change", " " # Replace 'Net change' with a space
    ).split(
        "24 Hour " # Remove '24 Hour' to avoid ambiguity.
    )[
        1: # slice 'Key metrics' from split
    ]
]

import itertools as it

print(list(it.chain.from_iterable(nested_tokens)))
```

OUTPUT: `['2120', '2290', '0616816']`

Comment: Thank you very much, this answered my question. However, my data that I want to get filtered is under a variable rather than in string-form and I would be unable to separate the 24 hour low and the 24 hour high. Is this still possible? My apologies for wording the question wrongly.

Comment: Please put a sample of the data that you want to filter, i.e. include the value of the variable that you want to use.

Comment: my variable is "stats" seen in "sequence = stats" example: "Key metrics24 Hour Low$21.2024 Hour High$22.90Net change$0.616816"

Comment: I included a solution that uses the sample string in your previous comment. Do you want to collect the data as type `float`? The strings without decimal points might not be so useful.

Comment: that looks promising, but I get an error saying that "is_digit" is an unresolved reference. Also, I get a bunch of traceback errors:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/barryn/web_s 2.0/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    nested_tokens = [
  File "/Users/barryn/web_s 2.0/main.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    [''.join(filter(is_digit, item)) for item in token.split()]
  File "/Users/barryn/web_s 2.0/main.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    [''.join(filter(is_digit, item)) for item in token.split()]
NameError: name 'is_digit' is not defined

Comment: `is_digit` is a function. Check the code in my answer. It is defined there. I usually try to avoid regular expressions. That said, the strings you are using might be complex and irregular enough to merit the consideration of using regular expressions.